# Android AsyncTask PostExecute

Tags: android

i use AsyncTask inside a function 
How to return a value when Async Finish Execution , since i cant use PostExecute method here

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {}}
```

Heres The Code.
I need to retrieve values from SpinnerList to use em on the main thread.
But usually i get null values whenever i ask for data , because it didnt return the values yet.

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try{
                    String fql = "SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE is_app_user  AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

                    parameters.putString("query", fql);
                    parameters.putString("method", "fql.query");
                    parameters.putString("access_token",  fb.getAccessToken());
                    String Response = fb.request(parameters);
                    JSONArray json = new JSONArray(Response);
                    list = new ArrayList<String[][]>();
                    String[][] friendsToList = new String[1][2];
                    SpinnerList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String TempToSpinnerList=new String();
                    for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); ++i){
                        friendsToList[0][0] = json.getJSONObject(i).getString("uid");
                        friendsToList[0][1] = json.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                        TempToSpinnerList= friendsToList[0][1];
                            list.add(friendsToList);
                            SpinnerList.add(TempToSpinnerList);
                            Log.e("Test"," "+friendsToList[0][1]+" "+friendsToList[0][0]);
                        }


                        //dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        //spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);



    /*  jsonUser = fb.request(parameters);
        friendObj = Util.parseJson(jsonUser);

        friendArray = friendObj.getJSONArray("data");

        //
        friendlist = new ArrayList<String[][]>();
        String[][] friendsToList = new String[1][2];
        int friendCount = 0;
        String fId, fNm;
        JSONObject friend;
        for (int i = 0;i<friendArray.length();i++){
            //Get a JSONObject from the JSONArray
            friend = friendArray.getJSONObject(i);
            //Extract the strings from the JSONObject
           friendsToList[0][0] = friend.getString("id");
            friendsToList[0][1] = friend.getString("name");
            friendlist.add(friendsToList);
            //Set the values to our arrays
         Log.e("Tester",""+ friendsToList[0][0]+" "+ friendsToList[0][1]);
            friendCount ++;}*/
            }
                catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FacebookError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }});
```

Comment: We can't tell what you're asking, you should elaborate. What are you trying to do? What have you tried?

Comment: Post all of your AsyncTask function for a better description, also you can assign values in the onPostExecute method of AsyncTask.

Comment: This is an outdated Android method of performing tasks in a new thread... Please see my post below using AsyncTask and move everything in your `try{}` block to inside the `doInBackground` function in my code below...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to perform some function once the Asynctask is complete, you can setup a callback function in the calling activity. Create a constructor in the AsyncTask class and pass it the calling activity. Then use this reference to call the callback function when your task is complete.

You can also update the UI from within onPostExecute, which is simpler if it works for you.

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    private MainActivity activity;

    public MyTask(MainActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Do background stuff
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
        //dismiss progress dialog if needed
        //Callback function in MainActivity to indicate task is done
        activity.taskDone("some string");
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
//Pass your params array and the current activity to the AsyncTask
new MyTask(MainActivity.this).execute(params);

//Callback for AsyncTask to call when its completed
public void taskDone(String returnVal) {
    //Do stuff once data has been loaded
    returnText = returnVal;
}
```

Comment: A related question here, does one need to guard against the calling activity being null (destroyed by Android due to user interaction or other reasons) when onPostExecute runs?  I plan to add code like this to disable a UI EditText until an app's database is setup via an AsyncTask.  In the onPostExecute, I plan to call a callback to enable the EditText.  This EditText should only be interactive after the DB is configured.  Do I need to worry about the calling activity  being null?

Answer (score 1):

You do not return values from AsyncTasks. You need to pass in whatever you want to change to the AsyncTask and in onPostExecute() you can change the value. Please post more code and a better explanation of your scenario for a complete answer.

EDIT: As Jamis0n stated below the the value the AsyncTask calculates can be "gotten" using the get() method as well.

Comment: This is not entirely true... doInBackground's return value can be obtained via `new myTask().execute(params).get();`, although it is not recomended as it ties up the main UI. My solution above utilizes a callback function in the calling activity, which sounds like what the OP wants

Comment: Although I somewhat regret pointing that out as I would never use it myself!