# Calling an activity from the post execute in an asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

I have a Class: GalleryLoop which contains all the details

I have a separate Class: LoadingScreenActivity that has an inner class that extends AsyncTask

I am trying to call the `.execute` in `LoadingScreenActivity` such that i could load the `GalleryLoop`

Is there any way i can execute without combining both Java CLass files?

The codes are as follows:

```
   private class LoadViewTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
    {
        //A TextView object and a ProgressBar object
        private TextView tv_progress;
        private ProgressBar pb_progressBar;

        //Before running code in the separate thread
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            //Initialize the ViewSwitcher object
            viewSwitcher = new ViewSwitcher(LoadingScreenActivity.this);
            /* Initialize the loading screen with data from the 'loadingscreen.xml' layout xml file. 
             * Add the initialized View to the viewSwitcher.*/
            viewSwitcher.addView(ViewSwitcher.inflate(LoadingScreenActivity.this, R.layout.loadingscreen, null));

            //Initialize the TextView and ProgressBar instances - IMPORTANT: call findViewById() from viewSwitcher.
            tv_progress = (TextView) viewSwitcher.findViewById(R.id.tv_progress);
            pb_progressBar = (ProgressBar) viewSwitcher.findViewById(R.id.pb_progressbar);
            //Sets the maximum value of the progress bar to 100             
            pb_progressBar.setMax(100);

            //Set ViewSwitcher instance as the current View.
            setContentView(viewSwitcher);
        }

        //The code to be executed in a background thread.
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            /* This is just a code that delays the thread execution 4 times, 
             * during 850 milliseconds and updates the current progress. This 
             * is where the code that is going to be executed on a background
             * thread must be placed. 
             */
            try 
            {
                //Get the current thread's token
                synchronized (this) 
                {
                    //Initialize an integer (that will act as a counter) to zero
                    int counter = 0;
                    //While the counter is smaller than four
                    while(counter <= 4)
                    {
                        //Wait 850 milliseconds
                        this.wait(850);
                        //Increment the counter 
                        counter++;
                        //Set the current progress. 
                        //This value is going to be passed to the onProgressUpdate() method.
                        publishProgress(counter*25);
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        //Update the TextView and the progress at progress bar
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) 
        {
            //Update the progress at the UI if progress value is smaller than 100
            if(values[0] <= 100)
            {
                tv_progress.setText("Progress: " + Integer.toString(values[0]) + "%");
                pb_progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
            }
        }

        //After executing the code in the thread
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
        {
            /* Initialize the application's main interface from the 'main.xml' layout xml file. 
             * Add the initialized View to the viewSwitcher.*/
            viewSwitcher.addView(ViewSwitcher.inflate(LoadingScreenActivity.this, R.layout.main, null));
            //Switch the Views
            viewSwitcher.showNext();
            //ImageView = viewSwitcher.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
    }
```

The other class file:

```
public class GalleryLoop extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
//details of Galleryloop
}
```

I am new to Android and I am not sure which of the following would be a better choice:

1.By initiating the GalleryLoop before the AsyncTask starts

2.Initiating the GalleryLoop within the AsyncTask (in the do_in_background)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes it's possible just create LoadViewTask class as separate call and then extend AsyncTask

Comment: May i know how to go about doing it??

Comment: I already have a LoadViewTask class and extends to AsyncTask. However, I want to be able to load the GalleryLoop on the post-execute function. A i suppose to create another class or??

Answer (score 1):

My answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863260/android-asynctask-postexecute/13863413#13863413) should help you... Use a constructor for the Asynctask class and pass the calling activity to the Asynctask...

Then you can call a callback function in the calling activity once Asynctask is finished.

This should allow you to use one class for your GalleryLoop activity and run the loading screen activity using Asynctask in the background, calling a callback function when complete.

Comment: If my preexecute is using viewswitcher, doInBackground is loading a progress bar, does it mean in my postexecute i would need to use viewswitcher to change the view to the GalleryLoop or i would need to remove the viewswitcher, dismiss the progress bar and load the GalleryLoop? I'm pretty confused as to how to do it.